# I want to add advertising in android application

Tags: android, ads

I want to add "ads" in my project. I have created an ad using the website admob.com I just need to know how can i add it to my project. I searched on google but I am not getting the correct answers. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this link , there's everything in details. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#android

Comment: i checked ths site but the thing is i am unable to import the jar file in my project. i mean when i import com.google.ads.*; m getting an error.

Comment: Copy and paste the jar file in your libs folder. Right click on this jar file and select "Add to build path". You are done.

Comment: Check your build path. Look at order and export , make sure the jar is checked. If it doesn't work , then remove this from build path , clean your project and do the same again.

Comment: You have made a silly mistake in any steps that are described.

Comment: m unable to get the MY_AD_UNIT_ID. can you tell me how will i know the id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39263/discussion-between-sherry-and-ayon)

Answer (score 0):

Here are simple steps to add an ad banner in your android app. 
Firstly add this method in your Main activity

```
private void displayAd()
{
 try
 {


  AdView adView = new AdView(LettersType.this, AdSize.BANNER, HERE-YOUR-ADMOB-ID);

   // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
   // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
  FrameLayout adMobLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.banner);



   // Add the adView to it
  adMobLayout.addView(adView);

 // AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
 // adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

   // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad

   adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
   adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

 public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {

 }


 public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {

 }

 public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {

 }

 public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {

 }

 public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {

 }

     });




 }catch(Exception e)
 {

 }
}
```

Add this permissions in android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

And finally add this in your mainactivity layout XML file

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/banner"             
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />
```

This framelayout is the adbanner .

Comment: Open android SDK manager in eclipse. In extras there is a google admobs SDK, install it.

Comment: Or Else.....if you got the jar with you. Right click on your project-properties and then select JAVA BUILD PATH from the list. and then select libraries option. On the right side there is an option called add external jars. Select it and navigate it to the .jar you got for admob. Clean the project and run it. ask me if you need anything else.

Comment: actually i tried using admob.com but i guess i have to pay fr it. is it so? coz i need to have the id in place of MY_AD_UNIT_ID

Comment: yes you need an admob account. But creating an account and getting an id is free. give it a shot. dont worry, its completely free.

Comment: but when i am trying to Add Site/App, i need to fill the payment details. dont know how to do it :(

Comment: http://support.andromo.com/kb/common-questions/how-to-get-an-admob-publisher-id this will help you for sure..upvote my answer...

Comment: im still unable to get the id

Comment: i think they changed the rules.